# Run gedit on OSX Mavericks?

Tags: macos, gedit, osx-mavericks

The Version of Gedit on the gnome.org site does not seem to run on OSX Mavericks. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: If you leave a close vote, please explain the purpose of the gedit tag for me. I want to understand the SO standards on this, not only for this question but future questions.

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but _I_ feel this question is more suited for SuperUser. I would expect the tags you mentioned to be used if the asker was writing Gedit plugins, or OSX apps.

Comment: [TextWrangler](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/textwrangler/id404010395?mt=12) is a good alternative.

Comment: FYI the current beta version (3.13.91) runs fine on Yosemite, did not need additional packages.

Comment: @austinmarton great news, but it's not the latest beta! (it's dated 2014-09-12).

Comment: Ah OK, I found it at http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/mac/gedit/beta/ so assumed it was

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When I tried it, the problem was the version of libxml2 packaged with gedit.

Use the command "[brew](http://brew.sh) install libxml2"

then `cp /usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.1/lib/libxml2.2.dylib /Applications/gedit.app/Contents/Resources/lib/`.

In the current version of `brew`, the directory has changed to 2.9.2 so:
then `cp /usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/lib/libxml2.2.dylib /Applications/gedit.app/Contents/Resources/lib/`.

Comment: to install xcode command line tools use xcode-select --install from terminal. then use ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)" to install brew

Comment: As an update, the Homebrew link has changed, the new command is `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Answer (score 12):

Having [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) installed and comments from above I was able to simply `rm /Applications/gedit.app/Contents/Resources/lib/libxml2.2*` and it used the system/macports library instead of the bundled one without error.

Comment: Fantastic. Works great.

Answer (score 8):

**Just to Revise:**

- Having **macports** installed correctly. (If you just updated from e.g. OSX Lion you need to migrate macports to your new **Maverics OSX System**, https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration)
- Downloading gedit-3.2.6-3
- `sudo port install libxml2`
- and `rm /Applications/gedit.app/Contents/Resources/lib/libxml2.2*`
- Open gedit and start Coding!

For my 13-inch, Early 2011 Macbook pro it worked just fine.

--

**If you want to use gedit from Terminal:**

add

alias gedit="open -a gedit"

to

~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 1):

Gedit 2.30.2 works. 
But your own plugin won't work on Gedit 2.30.2.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what your goal is, but i found a easier way with another program. If installing all of this starts to get tiersome (that's what i figured out at least, since xcode needed downloading and tampering), i found sublime text 2 to work very nicely.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. . For me gedit is quite a nice text editor. . Years ago it was by far my favorite on OSX, however there's now a lot of native options. . I tried Chocolat, and its very nice, although fairly expensive.

Comment: SublimeText is even more expensive than Chocolat (although it's my editor of choice.) A good free editor for Mac is TextWrangler.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the version of "libxml2.2.dylib", distributed with Gedit 3.2.6 is outdated.

Install "Xcode" from the App Store (if you have not already done so), then:

$ cp -p /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib /Applications/gedit.app/Contents/Resources/lib/libxml2.2.dylib

Answer (score 0):

One solution (I'm still interested in others) is the following:

- The latest version of Gedit (3.2.6-3)for OSX on the Gnome.org website crashes.
- The older Gedit 2.30.2 still runs.

Answer (score 0):

try version 2.26.3 of Gedit – it’s working for me on MOJAVE !
http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/mac/gedit/2.26/
Darek

Answer (score -1):

If I am guessing correctly, your aim is a GUI Text editor for convenience.

```
open /path/to/file
```

performs the same action as of double clicking on the file from Finder

Also if you want to use it with a specific application  like sublime text

```
open -a 'Sublime Text' /path/to/file
```